# Link two models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've two models and I'd like to use them all in one `View`.

```
public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }
     }




public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       // public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

I'd like to use these in one `View`. This is a bookstore app. With this, I'd like to display genres and author's names on my `Home` page.

Comment: youll need to create a new ViewModel and then bring these classes in.

Comment: Look up the term "ViewModel". It has been covered dozens of times here on Stackoverflow (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: What research have you done????  There are tons of example on the web regarding this topic!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do and return the combined view model back to the view

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

// This is what you bring back to your View
public class CombinedViewModel {

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Author Author {get; set;}
}
```